# Java Inheritance, How to achieve hierarchical inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

Can we achieve hierarchical inheritence in java, I've a scenario something like this

```
class Person {
     String name;
     int age;
     List<Address> addressList;
     
     // ... getters, setters
}
class Address {
    String state;
    String contry;
    // ... getters, setters
}

class ExtendedAddress extends Address {
    String street;
    // ... getters, setters
}

class ExtendedPerson extends Person {
    String occupation;
    List<ExtendedAddress> addressList;
    // ... getters, setters
}
```

But in the ExtebdedPerson class, the getters and setters give errors as their return type changes..

here either I need to change the name of addressList or manually write setter and getter logic.

I'll not be able to because these DTOs are generated by swagger..

Is there an approach I can follow here?
Or, Is there a way I can write my swagger yaml more effectively.

This is my swagger definition

```
Person:
  type: object
  properties:  
     name:
      type: string 
      description: "Name of the person"
     age:
      type: integer
      description: "Age of the person"  
     addressList:
      type: array
      description: "Address List"
      items:
       $ref: '#/definitions/Address' 
 Address:
  type: object
  properties:  
     state:
      type: string 
      description: "Name of the state"
     country:
      type: string 
      description: "Name of the country"
      
 ExtendedAddress:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Address'
    - type: object
  type: object
  properties:  
     street:
      type: string 
      description: "Name of the street"

 ExtendedPerson:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/Person'
  type: object
  properties:  
     occupation:
      type: string 
      description: "Name of the occupation"
     addressList:
      type: array
      description: "Address List"
      items:
       $ref: '#/definitions/ExtendedAddress'
```

Comment: For ExtendedPerson `List<ExtendedAddress> addressList;` should be `List<Address> addressList;`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Answer (score 1):

You can't override `getAddress` in that way.

The reason is that in `Person` you have said that `getAddress` returns a `List` that can take any kind of `Address` (`Address` itself or any class extending it).

However, in `ExtendedPerson`, you are trying to redefine `getAddress` saying that the `List` can now only contain `ExtendedAddress` objects. So `ExtendedPerson` can't fulfil the contract defined by `Person`.

For example: if I created another subclass of `Address`, say `DeliveryAddress extends Address`, I would be allowed to add `DeliveryAddress` objects to the `List` in `Person` but I would not be allowed to add them to the `List` from `ExtendedPerson`. Therefore `ExtendedPerson` cannot extend `Person`.

You will have to create a separate getter method or re-use the same one and cast the result.